# Displaying model fields in django in a dropdown list

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

so I'm writting a program for creating orders for specific users and items. My problem is when I'm trying to display all customers, products and statuses from this model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, choices=STATUS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

I have to do this manually:

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block main %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                customer
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" > {{ form.customer.1 }}</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" > {{ form.customer.2}}</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" > {{ form.customer.3}}</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" > {{ form.customer.4}}</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" > {{ form.customer.5}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

That's because when i tried making a loop which would just give them ids instead of numbers it just wouldn't show up.

Can anybody help me? :(

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *


class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order  # model do którego tworzymy formę
        fields = '__all__'  # pola które dzięki niej chcemy uzupełnić
```

Views.py

```
def createOrder(request):

    form = OrderForm # tworzymy obiekt który bedzie trzymał formę z plikuu forms.py

    if request.method == 'POST': # jeżeli meotda request-u to POST
        form = OrderForm(request.POST) # to zmieniami wartość obiektu na formę z requestem POST
        if form.is_valid(): # jeżeli forma jest prawidłowa
            form.save() # zapisz formę w bazie danych
            return redirect('/') # przekieruj na stronę główną

    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', {
        'form': form, # przekazujemy formę do html-a aby mogła zostać wyświetlona
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your forms.py ?
It should be done just like you want this with Django ModelForm.

You can even filter with some properties with it, like in example below:

```
class WarehouseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.Select, queryset=Item.objects.filter(name__in=['Test1', 'Test2']))

    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = ['item', 'location']
```

Because I see that the problem is not in the forms, but actually using them.

You should have form passed into your template by the view, like this:

```
def some_view(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(id = pk)
    form = OrderForm(instance = order)
    return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', {'form':form})
```

Then in the html you can even write:

```
<form methodd="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you want to render field by field, you can go with:
{{ form.customer }}

If you truly want to just have a loop go with

```
{% for customer in form.fields.customer.choices.queryset %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" > {{ customer }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

and it should more or less - work, but it will probably cause form.is_valid to not act as expected.

Comment: It is passed by the view. I also added it to the question.

Comment: Everything works great and shows but i just can't get it to display in a for instead of writting .1 .2 .3 etc.

Comment: I know, but then the form looks very basic and there is no way in styling it.

Comment: Yes but it is supposed to be displayed in a dropdown list from bootstrap, so i have to acces every option from form.customer. I can do that by typing form.customer.1 then .2 and so on, but it only works for a small number of customers. So i would want it in a loop like this for i in form.customer and then pass the i as an id  form.customer.i instead of form.customer.1 but it doesn't want to work when i do this.